# Do I need the constant of integration here?

Tags: integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I know for something such as $\int x^2 dx$ would be $\frac{1}{3}x^3 + C_1$ but if you have an equation such as $5y^3 = x^4 $ integrating both sides you would get $ \int 5y^3 dy = \int x^4 dy$,
$ \frac{5}{4}y^4 + C_1 = yx^4+ C_2$but my question is: do we need the constants on both sides (are they equal)? I thought they would be the same and cancel out but I'm not sure if I'm correct. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a valid step to integrate one side with respect to $y$ and the other side with respect to $x$.

Comment: I have taken note of this error and will change it.

Comment: The relation between $x$ and $y$ prevents you from integrating $\int x^4 dy$ as $yx^4+C$. My answer shows how we could hypothetically get an easily integration problem.

Comment: It seems I have a fundamental lack of understanding of integration, where is the best place to learn?

Comment: @tobi1066 You may wish to start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two arbitrary additive constants. The reason is that if you have an equation of the form
$$f(x,y) + C_1 = g(x,y) + C_2,$$ you could rearrange it as
$$f(x,y) = g(x,y) + \underbrace{(C_2-C_1)}_{C_3}$$
$$f(x,y)=g(x,y)+C_3$$

Comment: Do I even need the constant?

Comment: @tobi1066 In general, yes, but you just need one.

Comment: Yes, you need the constant

Answer (score 1):

They're not in general equal, but all that matters is their difference, so there's only one degree of freedom. You can represent this by writing a constant on just one side. But, as @MPW noted, you can't jum from $5y^3=x^4$ to $\int 5y^3dy=\int x^4dx$, but you *could* jump from the latter, if it were given (or if e.g. we instead started with $5y^3y^\prime=x^4$), to $\frac54y^4=\frac14x^5+C$.